# Detected when my app open from push notification when app close objective c

Tags: objective-c, push-notification

I need to detect when user open my app from push popup view when the app close.

I try this:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if (launchOptions != nil) {
          // Launched from push notification
          NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    }
}
```

But always `launchOptions` return nil.

Comment: that means your app was not closed, it was open...

Answer (score 0):

if loved this with this:

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
{

   if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
   {
      NSLog(@"push Application State Active");
   }
   else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive ||    application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground)
   {

   }

}
```